# Checkbox is not updating checked or not checked when an item from cart reducer is removed from cart modal in react native bouncy checkbox

Tags: react-native, checkbox

When I am on the menu page, the user can check menu items to add them to cart and then it adds the selected items to cart. If cart.selecteditems.length > 0, the user can open a cart modal and can also increase quantity or decrease or remove the item from the modal. But when the user removes the item and closes the modal, the checkbox of the menuitem which was removed will be still checked. I need to fetch the menu again so that the page could re-render and only the added items should be checked.

**Check Box Code**

```
const cart = useSelector(state => state.cart)

const checkedAlreadyAdded = (id) => {
   let alreadyExist = cart.selectedItems.findIndex((obj)=> obj.itemId == id)       i 
   if(alreadyExist < 0){
      return false
   }else{
      return true
   }
}


<BouncyCheckbox
   onPress={()=>addItemToCart(item)}
   isChecked={checkedAlreadyAdded(item.id)}                                                  
 />
```

So the checkox is not updating it's checked value when the cart reducer makes changes in selectedItems.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful to target the id of your object. In the findIndex function which checks your id, you target it with obj.itemId, while you send the item.id arguments at the component level.